# Email address for S3 bucket?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to:

- Create a custom email address for a specific directory within S3 bucket
- Store all mail sent to the address, including any attachments, as a flat file in that bucket

Does AWS provide any capability like this? If not, is there any way to do it without standing up a new mail server?

#### Update

I've found a few SaaS tools that provide similar functionality:

- [SMTP Logic](http://www.smtplogic.com/Default.aspx) provides an email gateway that can, among other things, route attachments or archive copies of mail to S3.
- [cloudmailin](http://www.cloudmailin.com/) offers attachment storage on S3 as a supplement to their primary email-to-webapp function.

If you use Google Apps and have the ability to push Atom feeds to S3, you can use the [Gmail inbox feed](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed). This might work for my specific case, but is not a very good general solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: see other answer about SES.

AWS doesn't have a service like that. But you can easily write a service and run it on a Micro for less than 20 dollars a month.

You could use a regular mail server, or a highly programmable one like [Lamson](https://github.com/zedshaw/lamson).

Comment: Why do you say that? SES natively supports [receiving emails and saving them to an S3 bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html) which seems to fit this use case.

Comment: Did not know about that.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at Receiving emails with Amazon SES [receiving email S3 action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html).